# Blurry Nav Bar when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I successfully fixed my nav bar on the top of my webpage when scrolling, but somehow it get's blurry when passing over certain divs (mostly sliders). Could someone give me a hand please?

http://www.clinicajardinsbenfica.pt/new.html

Thanks in advance!

edit: it seems the issue is only with chrome. no idea why.

edit2: here's a videoscreenshot with the issue http://www.screenr.com/mVEH

Comment: it looks like its rendering again .. that interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has some problems rendering fixed elements.

You should start adding the follwing to your fixed element(s):

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
```

`translateZ(0)` can be used to fix numerous of Chrome Bugs.

If that doesn't work, make sure there are no elements inside your fixed element's container which have an `opacity` of `0`. If so make sure they also have `display:none;`

If you still don't get a result, make sure you've the following:

```
html,body { 
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto
}
```

There is still an open bug issue at [chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574).

Comment: Which platform are you using? Mac/Windows? Which Chrome version?

Comment: Windows 8. Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m.

Are you having trouble replicating the issue?

Comment: Hmm it's working under Windows 7 Chrome 30.0 with this fix.. Are you sure you have applied it to the ul? I've updatet my post please check if that works for you.

Comment: I added your code to the ul and uploaded it into the server. the webpage is now updated but unfortunately, it still doesn't work, at least in my browser.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? I can't reproduce the issue. Some elements were jumping around before but this seems to be fixed now.

Comment: I already wiped cache and stuff, and when searching the page source, the new css is there

Comment: well, the issue still exists but I think your code attenuated it a lot. since it's a chrome only problem, and happening only in certain versions I think it's good enough. thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help you. I updated my post with another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about that broken background coming below that dotted border then add below given CSS to fix that

```
#nav li a {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-image: none !important;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: auto auto;
    float: left;
    font-family: GothamHTF-Medium;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 22px 0.85em 16px;
}
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: exactly, the issue continues

Comment: Are you talking about that broken background coming below that dotted border ?

Comment: just fixed the broken background (it wasn't broken in chrome, but it showed up when I moved to firefox). Thanks for pointing that out, I had to re-size some images.

The real issue seems to show up only on chrome. The nav bar gets blurry when scrolling over slider divs.. Like it's being moved or rendering again.

Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your nav stylings.

```
#nav{
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: just changed it by ftp and still doesn't work for me, unfortunately